# NSManagedObject validation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to validate a core data object using

```
var value: AnyObject? = .....
try managedObject.validateValue(&value, forKey: key)
```

However, when value is nil, it seems that NSNull is being passed as its contents to validator (an error no such selector - [NSNull length] is being thrown).

I think I need to construct a reference to a real null pointer and pass it to validate (in case value is nil). This is because optional, even a nil one is actually never pointing at NULL. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You shouldn't override that method, instead create attribute validation methods or override validateForInsert/Update/Delete, [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/how-smart-dumb-should-nsmanagedobjects-be/) is an article that could be helpful

Comment: Hi Joakim, I fail to see what you mean by "overriding". I haven't overriden anything, just using stock method that does basic length/regex/optional validations.

Comment: Sorry, I was jumping between different pages. What I mean in your case is that you shouldn't call it directly since this will be done by Core Data. Just implement/override the validation method you need.

Comment: The problem is - I need to check validation long before i save the context. (This is for UI level input validation).

Comment: Ok, personally I am not using this core data validation logic much but the problem here seems to be with the pointer anyway. Do you really define `value` as `AnyObject`, shouldn’t it be declared as the actual type of the property you are validating?